# Why is the column name repeated in parentheses for a unique key?

Tags: mysql

I created a table in phpMyAdmin. When I export my MySQL database, the unique key is defined as `` UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`) ``, with the column name repeated in parentheses:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beitraege` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  // smallint? (65000!)
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Why is the column name repeated in parentheses? What does that mean? Creating a table in MySQL (and not using phpMyAdmin), when do I need to use this parenthetical repetition, and are there cases where the parenthesis might contain the name of a different column?

Comment: I suggest you start reading the documentation of the tools you use. That is simply the syntax of the key definition: first the index name, then in parenthesis the definition, here a single column.

Comment: @arkascha The documentation for MySQL is vast and not easy to understand. Also, English is not my mother tongue, and programming terminology is English. If I search in my mother tongue, I rarely find what I need, and usually I lack the words to search in English. So if, apparently, you are familiar with the MySQL documentation, I would be grateful if you could post a direct link to the relevant section. Thank you.

Comment: Fair enough, though you surprise me: you English appears to be near perfect to me when I read your question... Anyways: take a look at the `create table` syntax definition: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html In there you see the definition of a standard key inside such a command: `{INDEX|KEY} [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...)`. As mentioned above: first the key name, then in parenthesis the columns used to define the key.

Comment: @arkascha Thank you, that's very kind of you. Now I better understand how to read the docs. (And I'm serious! Compared to the PHP docs, the MySQL docs always overwhelm and confuse me. Maybe they should do some docs-usability-testing with lay people instead of experts ...) And yes, I'm pretty fluent in English, but I lack the technical vocabulary. I mainly know English from reading fantasy fiction, and knowing the words for medieval stuff doesn't help with programming :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define indexes that span several columns. Imagine your table contains city names and you want to ensure the names are unique, but of course you can have cities with the same name in different states and countries. You can achieve that with:

```
UNIQUE KEY uniq_state_city (state, city)
```

Comment: Aha, aha! Now this is beginning to make sense! I was wondering why the name for the index would need to be different from the (one, single) column name, but if the unique key can consist of several columns, giving it a name is rather sensible. Thank you. And now I know where I need to read on: keys consisting of multiple columns. Great help, @Joni!

Answer (score 0):

The first `id` is the name for the index. The second `id` in parentheses is the column name. see [create table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)

Comment: Thank you. I was going to ask why, then, the primary key does not have a name, but found this: "In MySQL, the name of a PRIMARY KEY is PRIMARY." (So I actually did follow your link and attempt to read that page ;-)